# Should I use KeyGenerator or SecretKeyFactory?

Tags: java, cryptography

I need to implement DES in Java, and I am seeing examples for generating the key sometimes using `KeyGenerator` and sometimes using `SecretKeyFactory` and both seems to work.

The question is which approach is better or are they the same? If they are the same why two approaches?

Comment: Do not implement it on your own. Use a libary.

Comment: @verbose-mode I suspect "implement" is being used incorrectly here.

Comment: not sure what is meant here, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @user3310917 You've used the phrase "implement DES", which implies you plan to write the DES algorithm yourself. This is not recommended - you should use the existing Java libraries to perform DES operations (e.g. with `Cipher`). It's quite possible you used the word "implement" by mistake, when perhaps you meant "use".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have existing plaintext key material that you must use, then `SecretKeyFactory` is the way you convert that material into a `SecretKey` object.

However, if you need to generate a new key, use a `KeyGenerator`.

If you have an encrypted key, you can unwrap it using a `Cipher` object (see `Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE`). If you want to store and reload a key, place it in a `KeyStore`.

Comment: For official documentation (this helped me understand the answer better): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Engine